# React Swipe Tab Views Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, frontend, babeljs

I need "react tab views" in my front end application.
I am using react 0.14.8 and using "bable", so using es6 syntax.
Any easy to import library ?
I tried using react swipe views, but that doesn't work with the latest react and react dom version.

Answer (score 0):

This one works pretty well:

https://oliviertassinari.github.io/react-swipeable-views/

I'm using it in an app with meteorjs.

To install

```
npm install --save react-swipeable-views react-motion
```

and the to import:

```
import SwipeableViews from 'react-swipeable-views';
```

Hope it helps!